# Why does my D3 code break when I set the script type to module?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-modules

I am working on a project built with Javascrpt, jQuery, and Vite.js.  My colleague built a data visualization using D3 - a US states map - that I need to implement in the project on a specific page. They built the component using test data, my job is basically to load the component onto a page passing it actual returned data from an API call.

Everything in the test project works perfectly, but when I tried to implement this code into a script file in the project - literally copying and pasting from the working version - I got an error saying certain properties could not be read. After failing to debug for sometime, I randomly tried removing `type="module"` from the script tag link in HTML, and boom, everything worked. Does anyone have an idea of why this would be? I cannot get this code to run when the script type is set to module, except I need the script type to be set to module since I'm importing lots of components for other aspects of the page.

With the way the CodePen is set up, I couldn't replicate the issue since the HTML and JS files are automatically linked. But if you copy this code into your editor, and then in the html, set the the JS file to a module `  You'll see the issue.

Thanks. I'm at a total loss for what to do here. I could put all the D3 code in it's own script file, but then I have no way pass it variables from other files if it's not a module.

Comment: That's because JS modules automatically run in strict mode, and because of strict mode that `this` inside  your function won't be `window`, but undefined instead.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any way around this, as far as the D3 code itself? I'm thinking I need to keep the D3 code in a separate non-modular script, and and then dynamically load it on the modular script once I have the data.

Comment: Just change the `this` inside that function, it's just polluting the global object.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a different way to write those lines of code? I'm new to D3 and my colleague wrote this component.

Comment: Well, this has noting to do with D3, that's a pure javascript thing: you have to do that code working on "use strict" mode. There is the `this` issue I mentioned, then I saw a couple of undeclared variables in the for loops, etc. I suggest you to post a new question with the javascript tag, removing the D3 tag, asking how to debug that code for strict mode. You can also do it yourself, just checking the differences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode. If you opt to post a new question, copy the (relevant) code instead of linking the CodePen.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks again for your help, your comments helped me solve the problem. I just had to change the `this` as you said and use `window` instead

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, the following lines in my original code were not working in strict mode:

```
this.uStates = uStates;
this.uStatePaths = uStatePaths;
```

The fix was simple, I just needed to write the following instead:

```
window.uStates = uStates;
window.uStatePaths = uStatePaths;
```